# Is there a better way to prioritize a sub query instead of using TOP?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

Currently we are using SQL Server 2019 and from time to time we tend to use TOP (max INT) to prioritize the execution of a sub-query.
The main reason to do this is to make the starting result set as small as possible and thus avoid excessive reads when joining with other tables.

most common scenario in which it helps:

t1: is the main table we are querying has about 200k rows
t2,3: just some other tables with max 5k rows
pres: is a view with basically all the fields we use for presentation of e.g. product with about 30 JOINS and also containing table t1 + LanguageID

```
SELECT t1.Id, "+30 Fields from tables t1,t2,t3, pres"
FROM t1
 INNER JOIN pres ON pres.LanguageId=1 AND t1.Id=pres.Id
 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.vtype=t2.Id
 LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.color=t3.Id
WHERE 1=1
 AND t1.f1=0
 AND t1.f2<>76
 AND t1.f3=2
```

we only expect about 300 rows, but it takes about 12 seconds to run

```
SELECT t.Id, "10 Fields from tables t1,t2,t3 + 20 fields from pres"
FROM (
 SELECT TOP 9223372036854775807 t1.Id, "about 10 fields from table t1,t2,t3" 
 FROM t1
  INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.vtype=t2.Id
  LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.color=t3.Id
 WHERE 1=1
  AND t1.f1=0
  AND t1.f2<>76
  AND t1.f3=2
 ) t
INNER JOIN pres ON pres.LanguageId=1 AND t.Id=pres.Id
```

we only expect about 300 rows, but it takes about 2 seconds to run

Comment: I have no idea what you are referring to.  `TOP` selects a certain number of rows from a query and is only allowed in a subquery if you use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Yep. I'm trying to figure this one out too. It's completely unclear how a TOP operation will "prioritize" a sub-query. The optimizer doesn't prioritize. It uses row counts to determine access methods. A TOP operation will limit row counts, so it may be attractive to the optimizer from that standpoint, but I don't think that's what you mean.

Comment: What do you mean by prioritize? There's no change in execution priority just by using TOP.

Comment: I think some wrong terminology was use to describe the problem. Using `top` _can_ have a positive impact on performance with faster results (due to altered query plan), making it look like the query was "prioritized" over other queries. In reality the query just executed faster. The mention of "excessive reads" also points towards performance (instead of priority).